# How to replace for loop to numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my function to set value of 'cropped_inputs_final' array from 'cropped_inputs_index' array and 'inputs_data_list' array.

```
for i in range(cropped_inputs_final.shape[0]):
   a1 = int(cropped_inputs_index[i])
   cropped_inputs_final[i] = inputs_data_list[a1][0]
```

However, this for loop spend too much time.

Is there any way to replace for loop to numpy (or any else) to reduce the running time?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [vectorization](https://blog.paperspace.com/numpy-optimization-vectorization-and-broadcasting/), and is in general a very good thing, though it can be pretty counter intuitive sometimes.

I would need more context to give you an exact answer (what are the arrays shapes?), but [array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) seems to be what you need.

```py
cropped_inputs_final = input_data_list[cropped_input_index][0]
```

Comment: No worries, did it solve your pb ? If so do you mind accepting the answer ?